# Call function that returns table in a view in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

1. SQL Server - Compatibility Level 2000
2. `Person` table - PersonId, PersonName, etc.. (~1200 records)

Two user functions - `GetPersonAddress(@PersonId)`, `GetPaymentAddress(@PersonId)`

These two functions return data in a table with Street, City etc...(one record in the return table for the `PersonId`)

I have to create a view that joins the person table with these two user functions by passing in the person id.

Limitations:

- Cross Apply is not supported on a function in SQL Server 2000
- Cursor, temp table and temp variables are not supported in views so that I can loop upon the person table and call the functions.

Can someone help?

Comment: Why are you still using sql server 2000? It has been dead for a long time now. Long answer short, you can't do this in a view in sql server 2000. You could use a stored procedure though.

Comment: Probably not the answer you were looking for but [here is a link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads) to SQL Server downloads, where you can get yourself a version that is supported. SQL Server 2000 stopped being supported 4 and half years ago, and its successor, 2005 is not supported anymore either. As far as I am aware, there is no solution to your problem that is compatible with SQL Server 2000.

Comment: @GarethD - only possible supported path is (since they do mention *compatibility*) that they're running a 2008 R2 server in backwards compatibility. Of course, even that's only got two years left and they should be *fixing the compatibility issues* and moving forward, not developing new code under that compatibility mode.

Comment: sounds like your design is not very good.   GetPersonAddress and GetPaymentAddress sound like they should be scalar value functions.. if you want separate columns for each field, then why not just join to the tables with the address columns

Comment: @SeanLange Probably he is asking that because he have no other options. If one of your clients still use SQL 2000 (trust me, it's still used in production environments nowadays) and refuse to upgrade (usually because it cost them money), you have to look for a workaround, I have been in that situation.

Comment: Yes, i had no other option as in converting to 2005 or beyond  which is not in my control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create functions `GetPeopleAddresses()` and `GetPaymentsAddresses()` which return PersonId as a field and then you can use them in `JOIN`:

```
SELECT t.PersonId, PersonName, etc..., a1.Address, a2.Address
FROM YourTable t 
  LEFT JOIN GetPeopleAddresses() a1 ON a1.PersonId = t.PersonId
  LEFT JOIN GetPaymentsAddresses() a2 ON a2.PersonId = t.PersonId
```

Of course, your functions have to return only unique records

Comment: I don't think that this solves his problem, the table functions he is using have `@PersonID` as a parameter and you need `CROSS APPLY` to feed that parameter to the function (which he can't use because of SQL2000 requirement).

Comment: Thanks Denis, this worked for me and is the best efficient under my current circumstances. Had to re-design the function to return based on your suggestion and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you can't do that with a view in SQL Server 2000 because of the limitations you listed. The next best option as suggested in the comments is a stored procedure that returns the rows that would return the view.

If you need to use the results of the procedure in another query, you can insert the values returned by the procedure in a temporal table. Is not pretty, and you have to make two DB calls (one for creating/populating the temp table, and the other for using it), but it works. For example:

```
create table #TempResults (
  PersonID int not null,
  Name varchar(100),
  Street varchar(100),
  City varchar(100),

  <all the other fields>

  constraint primary key PK_TempResults (PersonID)
)

insert into #TempResults
exec spTheProcedureThatReplaceTheView @thePersonID
go -- end of the first DB call


select <fields>
from AnotherTable
join #TempResults on <condition>

-- don't forget to drop table when you don't need its current data anymore
drop table #TempResults
```

Comment: Thanks Alberto, it is a good suggestion but the twice db calls were a concern . Hence decided on redesigning the function which worked clean

Comment: If that is and option then is better doing that, but note that two joins with the two table-function could slow the query if the number of rows grow significantly (with just a few thousand of rows should be no problem, though) .